# MS access Group by

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

I have a big access database table and part of it is given below and  I want to get the minimum value by group, which is the minimum value for 3, 5, 9,.... I have tried in the query using minimum value of Group by but it couldn't give me:

I want like:

```
Point     ParaA                  Modvalue             MinofParaA
    3        0.02345610000       1.1304602327522
    5       0.541734307717087   0.592591581187
    7       4.4094560894325      0.393245327246
    9       5.5450476528689        1.034165859885
    11           …..                 …….
    13          …….                …….
```

Part of my database is:

```
Point   ParaA                 Modvalue
    3   1.01537282042687E-07    1.1304602327522
    3   5.41734307717087E-06    1.592591581187
    3   4.4094560894325E-05     2.393245327246
    3   5.5450476528689E-05      1.034165859885
    3   5.6210847721211E-05     1.9269298608176
    3   7.33007048018759E-05    3.17251848741499
    3   1.26935918181651E-04    7.577150615919
    3   1.27908837646644E-04    4.466340029852
    9   0.205576008517929       32.1580666011739
    9   0.2058403012141        6.080246238675
    9   0.205888794863275   4.48451872092713
    9   0.205970780609684   30.2695831828562
    9   0.206476048361761   2.3287221969481
    9   0.206500794273712   4.48657381393526
    9   0.206507173199086   3.54388543810806
    9   0.206701769548586   77.5713240109687
    5   0.127510144904596   0.692657575677875
    5   0.127593565284236   16.812067790848
    5   0.127765437607527   1.5228257707606
    5   0.12803789311445    13.185719005611
    5   0.12821555669427    15.488318488284
    5   0.128929582513692   1.24166466944275
    5   0.129137495154857   20.811097854043
    5   0.129492706221109   1.73300570963531
    5   0.130290993399936   6.7783307471853
    5   0.130328615583637   11.879218642047
```

I have tried like: Group by and min (minimum value) but it doesn't give me what I want.

Comment: What is the difference between `ParaA` and `MinofPara` ?

Comment: I want the minimum value of point 3, 5,.. (one value) of paraA and don't worry about the value. I just want the minimum vaue (one value) for each point.@Time Biegeleisen. MinofPara was obtained after I was trying to get the minimum value of paraA in access but it gives me as shown above.

Comment: I suggest that your fix your sample data such that it is consistent.  I am seeing values in the expected output which do not even appear in the sample input given.

Comment: Rather than giving me a single minimum value from each point, it keeps me giving the whole value without grouping and I don't know way and whatever the sample data, I would think it sould come down to one minimum value and I don't where thins go wrong!

Comment: Please post actual SQL query so we can help with how you are calculating grouped minimums.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you please look at @Lee mac answer and correct it. I want the minimum value of paraA with corresponding value of Modvalue and group by Point.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided in the comments, perhaps something along the following lines yields the result that you require:

```
select t.point, first(t.paraA), min(t.minofpara)
from YourTable t
group by t.point
```

The second column of this query essentially returns the value of a 'random' record within each point group. Change `YourTable` to the name of your table.

**EDIT:** Based on your comments to my answer, it seems that you simply require:

```
select t.point, min(t.paraa)
from YourTable t
group by t.point
```

To select the record(s) which hold this minimum, you might then use:

```
select t1.* from YourTable t1 inner join
(
    select t2.point, min(t2.paraa) as mp
    from YourTable t2
    group by t2.point
) t3 
on t1.point = t3.point and t1.paraa = t3.mp
```

Comment: Thanks, @Lee Mac, but I only want the minimum value of ParaA grouped by points and I won't consider MinofPara, because minofpara is the result that I got when I did the access. just consider point and ParaA so that I will get the minimum value of ParaA grouped by point,i.e, single minimum value for each point (3,5...)

Comment: thanks, how do you select any variable (I have one variable) corresponds to this minimum value. I want that variable, i.e, I don't want any min or max of this variable, but I want to select the variable value that corresponds to the min value of ParaA.

Comment: Thanks again@ Lee Mac I think the last updated answer holds everything, can you describe what t1, t2, and t3 means so that I won't do a mistake? I understand t.point from the previous answer but is t1 different from t.point?

Comment: You're welcome. `t1`,`t2`, & `t3` are merely aliases to: (1) save me typing `YourTable` repeatedly, and (2) allow me to reference `YourTable` more than once within the same query (as `t1` and `t2`).

Comment: I got an error says (JOIN expression is not supported).  I edited the question and I want the minimum value of paraA  grouped by the poing with the corresponding value of modvalue. I need your last effort of assisting me taking into consideration of those variables @Lee Mac.

Comment: Did you replace all occurrences of `YourTable` with the name of your table? The posted SQL works fine in my testing with your data. I've tweaked the final SQL to only output fields from `t1`, rather than from all joined tables.

Comment: Ya, I substitute my table in place of t1, t2 and t3. I don't know why I am still getting an error, may be, would it be possible for  you to substitute those variables in case, thanks@Lee Mac

Comment: what do I put in t3.mp? I thought I put mytablename.mp. right?

Comment: please also note that I have all the fields in one table/query, I don't have many tables.

Comment: No - you don't need to change `t1`,`t2`,`t3`, only replace all occurrences of `YourTable` with the name of your table.

Comment: It doesn't give me, what do I put on the first line of code, select t1...I thought the variable in t1.point, not the name of the table. isn't it?